# Python code not showing anything when ran

Tags: python

I have code that i am trying to run in but nothing is being printed.

```
def linear_search(list, target):
for i in range(0, len(list)):
    if list[i] == target:
        return i
    return None

def verify(index):
    if index is not None:
        print("Target found at index:", index)
    else:
        print("Target not found in the list")

        numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

    result = linear_search(numbers, 12)
    verify(result)
```

Can anyone assist?

Comment: You need to add a main to run your code, see more information here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do

Comment: @imolinuevo Very misleading. There's no need for a "main", just for unindented code.

Comment: The way the code is indented, nothing will be done. The first for should be indented compared to the "def linear_search". And with the way the for loop is written, that loop would only run with the value i=0. Afterward, if it is equal target, it will return 0. If not, it will return None.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the current state of your code, you just define two functions, so it is normal that nothing is displayed. But shouldn't you unindent the last three rows so that they are not included in 'verify' definition?